# Enabling OpenMp on visual studio gives an error message

Tags: openmp

Why would enabling OpenMp for a certain application return this error message "Fatal User Error 1002: Not all work-sharing constructs executed by all threads" when I try to run it on Visual Studio? This happens without even adding any parallel constructs, and it only happens with this application, meaning when I try to execute other application with OpenMp enabled this doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Express or Professional Studio?

Some of this project properties can be wrong...

Comment: I have Visual studio  professional 2008, I don't know what project properties might be interfering with Openmp :(